# What's the proper way to grab an object from my Entities dictionary in a Normalized state and pass it to a component?

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I have a state that looks like:

```
entities: {
  pageDict: {
   ['someId1']: { name: 'page1', id: 'someId1' },
   ['someId2']: { name: 'page2', id: 'someId2' },
   ['someId3']: { name: 'page3', id: 'someId3' }
  }
}
lists: {
  pageIdList: ['someId1', 'someId2', 'someId3']
}
```

And a Component that looks like:

```
const Pages = ( props ) => {
  return (
    <div>
       props.pageIdList.map(( pageId, key ) => {
         return (
           <Page
             key={ key }
             pageObj={ somethingHere }  // What to do here?
           />
         );
       })
    </div>
  );
}
```

To grab the object, I would need to do:

```
let pageObj = state.entities.pageDict[ pageId ];
```

I guess I can pass the state.entities.pageDict as props from the Containers.. but I'm trying to look at the selectors pattern and looking at this:

https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/ComputingDerivedData.html

and I'm wondering if I'm doing this wrong, can someone give me some insight?  I just want to make sure I'm doing this correctly.

EDIT: I got the idea of using Entities from the https://redux.js.org/docs/recipes/reducers/NormalizingStateShape.html and the SoundCloud Redux project

EDIT2: I'm looking at things online like this https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/584 but I'm questioning if I'm using this incorrectly and I'm not sure how to apply this to my own project

EDIT3: I'm leaning on creating a selector that will get the pageIdList and return a list of the pageobjects from the pageDict.. that way I already have the object to pass into my Page component.

Comment: What is `pageIdList` and what object do you need in `pageObj` ? It is not clear based on your state structure

Comment: @klugjo pageIdList holds a list of page Ids.. it can be reordered/add/delete by the user.. any ID that is inside the pageDictionary.  i will edit the OP so it's more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I follow what you're trying to do here. With Redux try thinking of your user interface as always displaying something immutable: rather than "passing something to it" it is "reading something from the state". That when when your state changes your user interface is updated (it isn't always this simple but it is a pretty good start).

If I read your answer correctly you have a Map of pages:

```
//data
{ 
  id1: {...pageProperties} },
  id2: {...pageProperties} },
  id3: {...pageProperties} },
}
```

and your page list is the order these are displayed in:

ex:

```
[id2, id3, id1]
```

Your page object might look something like this:

```
//Page.js
class Page extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { pageIdList, pageEntities } = this.props //note I'm using props because this is connected via redux
    return (
      <div>
        { pageIdList.map((pageId, index)=>{ 
          return <Page key={index} pageEntity={pageEntities[pageId]} />  //I'm just pulling the object from the map here
        }}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
//connect is the Redux connect function
export default connect((store)=> { //most examples use "state" here, but it is the redux store
  return {
    pageEntities: store.pageEntities,
    pageIdList: store.pageList
  }
})(Page)
```

Now when we want to change something you update the state via a dispatch / action. That is reduced in the reducer to display the new state. There are a lot of example out there on how this works but the general idea is update the state and the components take care of displaying it.

The result of this code (and there might be some typeos) is that you should see:

Page id: 2, Page id: 3, Page id: 1 because the list of the pages in the state is 2, 3, 1 in the example I gave.

To answer your question specifically what the entity I'm pulling is the global Redux Store (not the internal component state). 'Map State to Props' is really 'Map Store to Props' as the 'state' is part of React and the 'store' is your Redux store.

Does that help? React+Redux is really nice once you figure it out, it took me a solid month to understand all the ins and outs but it really does simplify things in the long run.